# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)" even after uses provider or connect

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm trying to use redux in my project I make my code like tutorial but it won't work and give error

I see most of the question about this error but I already done what they say the soultion like I should warp my root componet with provider or use connect

```
 Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import placesReducer from './src/store/reducers/places';
import{createStore} from 'redux'
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const RNRedux = () => (
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>
 );

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

**APP.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

 class App extends Component {

render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   some code
  </View>
  );
 }
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
some code
 };
  };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
   some code

};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**my store**

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from 'redux';

import placesReducer from './reducers/places';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
places: placesReducer
 });
```

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer)

```
 export default configureStore;
```

Comment: `console.log(store)` before RNRedux. Post the result please. My sneaking suspicion is you're not exporting a function in `./src/store/configureStore`, or returning a proper store that you're passing to the provider.

Comment: i edit the post with store file

Comment: i am new at react native so i didn't know debug yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer)
```

configureStore in this case is a variable with the return value of createStore, you most likely want it to be a function.

Comment: It was like this this in the beginning but also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

do you have to call configureStore as callback?
can you call it directly like that:

```
const configureStore = createStore(rootReducer);
```

Comment: I think you're exporting your App component twice, now that i read it more through.
try this removing the export from the class component.

Comment: sorry but also doesn't work , i even copy the tutorial files throw the same error
 i edit with the code with last edits